# custom array sorting withe special parent

Tags: php, arrays

I have question about array,

```
$source = array(
        array("id"=>1,"parent"=>0),
        array("id"=>2,"parent"=>6),
        array("id"=>3,"parent"=>5),
        array("id"=>4,"parent"=>6),
        array("id"=>5,"parent"=>0),
        array("id"=>6,"parent"=>8),
        array("id"=>7,"parent"=>0),
        array("id"=>8,"parent"=>10),
        array("id"=>9,"parent"=>0),
        array("id"=>10,"parent"=>0),
           );

$result = array(
        array("id"=>1,"parent"=>0),
        array("id"=>2,"parent"=>6),
        array("id"=>6,"parent"=>8),
        array("id"=>3,"parent"=>5),
        array("id"=>5,"parent"=>0),
        array("id"=>4,"parent"=>6),
        array("id"=>6,"parent"=>8),
        array("id"=>7,"parent"=>0),
        array("id"=>8,"parent"=>10),
        array("id"=>10,"parent"=>0),
        array("id"=>9,"parent"=>0),
           );
```

i want source array become to result array,
if item (like id 2,i as this one a) in array have a parent is not 0(actual is 6 ), the item (id equal 6) will append to item (id equal 2),others also doing this,finally we will remove item (id equal 6)....
please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$by_id = array(); //index the source array by id
//so we can find the parent quickly

foreach($source as $v) {
    $by_id[$v['id']] = $v;
}

$result = array();

foreach($source as $k => $v) {

    $result[$v['id']] = $v;

    //if the parent is 0 or has already been added
    //then move to next element
    if($v['parent'] == 0 || isset($result[$v['parent']]))
        continue;

    //otherwise add the parent
    $result[$v['parent']] = $by_id[$v['parent']];
}

$result = array_values($result);
print_r($result);
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/v5q8lR)